# using oauth2 web app in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, oauth2

i have a web app authenticated app, i manage to get an auth code, after which i get an access token but when i use the access token i get 403 with no explanation.

this is the url i use to get the authorization code:

https://my_subdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A4000%2F

after i get the authorization code i do the following POST:

```
POST /v2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: my_subdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "code": "auth_code_recieved_from_preivous_request",
  "client_id": "my_client_id",
  "client_secret": "my_client_secret",
  "redirect_uri": "https://127.0.0.1:4000/"
}
```

the result i get is:

```
{
    "access_token": "access_token",
    "refresh_token": "ref_token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1079,
    "scope": "tracking_events_write event_notification_subscription_delete event_notification_subscription_update event_notification_subscription_read event_notification_subscription_create event_notification_callback_delete event_notification_callback_update event_notification_callback_read event_notification_callback_create marketing_cloud_connect_send marketing_cloud_connect_write marketing_cloud_connect_read ott_channels_write ott_channels_read ott_chat_messaging_send ott_chat_messaging_read workflows_read tags_read approvals_read tags_write approvals_write workflows_write webhooks_write webhooks_read users_write users_read accounts_write accounts_read campaign_write campaign_read calendar_write calendar_read tracking_events_read file_locations_write file_locations_read data_extensions_write data_extensions_read list_and_subscribers_write list_and_subscribers_read web_write web_publish social_write social_read social_publish social_post sms_write sms_send sms_read push_write push_send push_read email_write email_send email_read journeys_write journeys_read journeys_execute automations_write automations_read automations_execute saved_content_write saved_content_read documents_and_images_write documents_and_images_read offline",
    "soap_instance_url": "https://my_subdomain.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/",
    "rest_instance_url": "https://my_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"
}
```

using this access token i do this final get response expecting to get the journeys but instead i get 403:

```
GET /interaction/v1/interactions HTTP/1.1
Host: my_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

what am i missing?

Comment: It sounds like a permission error. Check the scope you have given to the app. Does the user you are using have access to the "/interaction/v1/interactions" endpoint?

Comment: yeah, you are correct, i answered what was missing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The flow was correct, the login i was using only had an administrator role, i needed to use a login with more roles which allow data access.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111869)

Comment: edited the answer, i think it is more clear now